# Error when using DBCA to create database

Tags: oracle, oracle-18c

I am using Oracle Database XE (18c). The install completed without any error however, when I try to create a database using dbca it shows error: java.lang.NullPointerException.

[image: Error Image]

The log is:

https://ghostbin.com/paste/G0SEb

I am still very new to Oracle. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in your log file:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Global Settings
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

- Global database name : course_management
- Configuration type : Oracle Single Instance database
- SID : coursemanage
```

Global Database Name is meant to be a fully qualified name, like "sales.us.example.com". The first part of that name becomes the "SID" value, *and must not exceed 8 characters in length* (e.g. "sales.us"). In other words, pick a *much* shorter name.

See here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/ssdbi/about-assigning-global-database-names-during-installation.html#GUID-1AC9E18F-0AE4-4263-B3CC-A83B859A178F

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked.