# Error when creating new database using Oracle DCA

Tags: oracle-18c

I am getting NullPointerException while trying to add new database using Oracle 18c
[image]

trace log is here:
https://jpst.it/3cTNF

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: Please post all relevant information here. And textual information is better as text, not an image.

Comment: it's the same issue here but with a different cause I think
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/282327/error-when-using-dbca-to-create-database